# Access to worksheet where the macro belongs

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to access a worksheet where the macro belongs. To do that, I'm using this code snippet.
Is there another way to do it without using the name of this file?

```
Workbooks("file.xlsm").Activate
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

sheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "message"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worksheet or Workbook?? This is possible to access workbook where the macro belongs. In such case use `ThisWorkbook` reference where you have `Workbooks("file.xlsm")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibility to access Workbook where you macro is located. In such case use:

```
ThisWorkbook
```

where you have:

```
Workbooks("file.xlsm")
```